# Objective-C: understanding ARC

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

I am new to Objective-C. Here is my understanding (as in comments) concerning ARC of some simple code for programmatically adding a subview. Please correct me if I am wrong. Especially on this statement:

> "ViewController points to myView weakly" ACTUALLY means that _myView
>   (ViewController's ivar) points to a UIView object weakly

```
// _myView stores a pointer pointing to a UIView object
// "ViewController points to myView weakly" ACTUALLY means that _myView (ViewController's ivar) points to a UIView object weakly

@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic,weak) UIView *myView;
@end

@implementation
@synthesize myView = _myView;
@end

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [superviewDidLoad];
    CGRect viewRect = CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100);

    // a UIView object is alloc/inited    
    // mv is a pointer pointing to the UIView object strongly (hence the owner of it)
    UIView *mv = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:viewRect];

   // _myView points to the UIView object weakly 
   // Now the UIView object now have two pointers pointing to it
   // mv points to it strongly
   // _myView points to it weakly, hence NOT a owner 
   self.myView = mv;

   // self.view points to the UIView object strongly
   // Now UIView object now have THREE pointer pointing to it
   // Two strong and one weak
   [self.view addSubview:self.myView];
}   

// After viewDidLoad is finished, mv is decallocated. 
// Now UIView object now have two pointer pointing to it. self.view points to it strongly hence the owner, while _myView points to it weakly.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mostly correct, with the exception of this sentence:

> After viewDidLoad is finished, mv is decallocated.

That's where you are wrong. Remember, deallocation of an object only ever happens when everyone who `retain`'s the object `release`'s it.  Thus, while you have `release`'d the temporary variable `mv`, You still have one other source retaining it: `self.view.subviews`. Once `mv` is removed from the subview array, it can properly be cleaned up, `_myView` is set to `nil`, and you have no more leaks.

Comment: Sorry my bad. Actually what I am trying to say is: After viewDidLoad is finished, mv (a strong pointer) is set to nil. Is that a correct expression?

Comment: mv is a local variable. Once it leaves the scope of viewDidLoad it is set to nil.

Comment: @Abizern + 1 Abizern. Good comment!